# Divs disappearing when I resize the browser window

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

Please bear with me, I am still a beginner at front end development.
I am trying to create a responsive website using CSS Grid but got stuck now since my "hamburger" menu and footer just keep disappearing when I resize the window. I know the code is far from good, but I would kindly like to ask you for some help as I am getting frustrated. Should I somehow use media queries to fix this issue or something else?

Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hamburger_btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".hamburger_info").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #0F1014;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr repeat(2, 1.5fr) 0.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 2fr 0.5fr;
  grid-gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "leftbar main main rightbar" "footer footer footer footer";
}

.footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1.1fr 0.9fr;
  grid-gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: ". . ." "copyright copyright copyright";
  grid-area: footer;
  text-align: center;
  top: 150%;
  position: relative;
}

.copyright {
  grid-area: copyright;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.leftbar {
  grid-area: leftbar;
}

.rightbar {
  grid-area: rightbar;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) 0fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: "name menu ." "name menu .";
  grid-area: main;
}

.name {
  grid-area: name;
  width: 100vh;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  top: 35%;
  left: 25%;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_btn {
  width: 3.13em;
  height: 3.13em;
  margin: 0 auto 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_btn>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3.13em;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_btn .one {
  top: 25%;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_btn .three {
  top: 65%;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_info {
  width: 10em;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -10px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_info ul li {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_info ul li a {
  padding: 0.63em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #757575;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_info ul li:hover {
  background: #c62020;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_info ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_info:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.19em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-top: 0.63em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.63em solid #fff;
  border-left: 0.63em solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.63em solid transparent;
}

.grid-container .hamburger_btn.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.grid-container .hamburger_btn.active .one {
  top: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.grid-container .hamburger_btn.active .two {
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid-container .hamburger_btn.active .three {
  top: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.grid-container .main .hamburger_info.active {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}

.fa {
  padding: 1.25em;
  font-size: 1.88em;
  width: 5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: #c62020;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fa-facebook {
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
  background: #0F1014;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #0F1014;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fa-envelope-o {
  position: relative;
  right: 80%;
  background: #0F1014;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="footer">
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="contact.html" class="contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
      <div class="copyright">Copyright © 2020, NAME. All rights reserved.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="leftbar"></div>
    <div class="rightbar"></div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="name">
        <header>NAME</header>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="hamburger_btn">
          <div class="one"></div>
          <div class="two"></div>
          <div class="three"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger_info">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="design.html">Graphic Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Fersek
I already tested your code,
I already found the answer but I won't be showing to you because
i basically rewrite the whole grid thing.
What happening here is that you don't really need grid system to write a navbar.
That an over kill. Assuming you are making a responsive system
What most people do is that they usually use flex to tackle this prob.

The best answer I can give you is 
Please search for other people code and try to replicate their works. Then if you are not satisfied, try upgrading them first rather than writing from scratch like this

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and your tips. Will definitely try the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    .name {
      width: 100vh; /* Remove this */
    }
    .hamburger_btn {
      float:right; /* If you want it to go right */
    }
```

Comment: Please comment your answer for more clarity : where to write your code, if this is using a media query or not ...

Comment: Thank you very much this actually fixed the issue I was having!